# Google Places Api getting exact place from longitude and latitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google places json api and I was wondering how do I get a place's name and information if my longitude and latitude given is in the vicinity. For example I went on google maps and I got the exact location of a Starbucks and this is the link I provided to the api

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=53.565936,-113.273824&radius=1&key=(APIKEY)`

However the response I get is only my locality information

Is my url correct or is there a different way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Google Geocoding API.. Heres the tutorial on it:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Specifically you want a request that looks like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

That is directly from their page, good luck.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response, however I tried this before and it doesn't seem to return the location name for me even though my coordinates are in a location with a name

Comment: Are you sure you're passing it in correctly? It should return a "formatted address" field that contains what I believe you're looking for. You should just be passing in the latlng= field and your key, thats it.